# Block certain script in the Chrome / Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

Is there a way to block, let's say `some_script.js` from `domain.com`, but not all of them?

Answer (score 13):

I think you can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698059/disable-single-javascript-file-with-addon-or-extension)

> AdBlock for Chrome can be used to block JS files.....
>   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom
>   ...Click on the AdBlock icon and select "Show the resource list" and
>   look for the JS you want to block and tick the box next to it and make
>   your selections.
>   **Note**   In settings, "I'm an advanced user, show me advanced options." should be selected.

Comment: This led me in the right direction.  As for me in chrome in the year 2016, I found that adblock plus extension integrates itself with the F12 developer tools in chrome.  What I did was press F12 in chrome, and select the Adblock Plus tab.  Then select the 'SCRIPT' type from the dropdown at the top. Next to the scripts as you mouseover, will be a button for each script to "Block Item".  The action can also be undone from the same screen in the same way. After you block the scripts you wish, just refresh the original page.

Comment: Sweet, thanks! Our company installed a plugin for redmine that basically killed productivity while using it outside selected tasks, this answer helped me get control back.